# How to deep copy a Yii 1.x model

Tags: yii, model, copy, clone, relation

I was searching for a simple solution to deep copy Yii models including all relations (update foreign id and stuff) but could not find something satisfying so far.

So I came up with a solution and want to discuss it with you.

I have extended CActiveRecord and added this copy method. What do you think?

```
/**
 * @return BaseModel
 */
public function copy() {
    $newModel = new static();
    $newModel->attributes = $this->attributes;
    $newModel->save();

    foreach ($this->relations() as $property => $relationDefinition) {
        list($type, $refModel, $refProperty) = $relationDefinition;

        if ($type == self::HAS_MANY) {
            foreach ($this->$property as $oldRefModel) {
                /** @var BaseModel $newRefModel */
                $newRefModel = $oldRefModel->copy();
                $newRefModel->$refProperty = $newModel->id;
                $newRefModel->save();
            }
        } else if ($type == self::HAS_ONE) {
            /** @var BaseModel $newRefModel */
            $newRefModel = $this->$property->copy();
            $newRefModel->$refProperty = $newModel->id;
            $newRefModel->save();
        }
    }

    return $newModel;
}
```

Comment: Good. Also I recommend to move cloning relations to new method.

Comment: I think this should be done by defining a `__clone()` method and using the `clone` keyword for copying objects, since that is the PHP standard way to address this issue. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php